# How to send the base 64 encoded string from android to wcf

Tags: android, wcf

I wrote the functionality to encode an image and send it to wcf. Um not using query string parameters. Um using the URL to pass parameters. This is my android code and this works fine.

```
public JSONUpdate(String jobNumber, String documentType,
        String documentFilePath, String DocumentFileName,
        String encodedImage, String url) {

    this.url = url + jobNumber.trim() + "/" + documentType.trim() + "/"
            + documentFilePath.trim().replace("/", "___") + "/"
            + DocumentFileName.trim() + "/" + encodedImage;
}



 public boolean updateService() {
    boolean result = false;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(this.url);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            if (httpResponse != null) {
                if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                    result = true;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String p = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        String y = ex.getMessage();
    }
    if (!result) {

    }
    return result;
}
```

In my WCF implementation that also works fine except whenever I include encoded string parameter it throws an error because encoded string contains the '+' and '\'. So the URL getting broken. This is my WCF code for the service

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "attachment/{jobNumber}/{documentType}/{documentFilePath}/{DocumentFileName}/{encodedImage}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public bool InsertAttachment(String jobNumber, String documentType,
        String documentFilePath, String documentFileName,
         String encodedImage = null)
    {
        //implementation was written
    }
```

how to pass the encoded 64 bit string safely as the parameter with + and \ ? I do not have much experience on it. I will b grateful if anyone can give me a suggestion.

Comment: What is your target Android version?

Comment: Android 3.0 is my android version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Android [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) implementation which is aviable since API 8.

```
Base64.encodeToString(youtString.getBytes(...), Base64.NO_WRAP + Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

Comment: can we apply this in to an image ?

Comment: Sure as long the image is in a byte array.

Comment: But why am I getting an out of memory exception ? when put this in to http post?

Comment: Maybe the image is too big for encoding it in memory? You should note that the encoding consumes about 30-40% more memory than the plain image.

Comment: well most probably :) anyway Thank you